# wgetpaste alternatives?

Tags: linux, command-line, utilities

Are there any wgetpaste alternatives?

As a clarification...

> wgetpaste is an extremely simple command-line interface to various
>   online pastebin services.

The basic usage is to simply upload a local file to a pastebin-like online service for sharing.

Comment: When you ask a question like this, you should explain what wgetpaste is (write a sentence or two, and link to the home page or Wikipedia article or something), and say what you're looking in an alternative (extra feature, easier to use, more portable, …).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I use an online service called [sprunge.us](http://sprunge.us/). It lets you post pretty simply like this

```
command | curl -F "sprunge=<-" http://sprunge.us
```

I have `curl -F "sprunge=<-" http://sprunge.us | xclip` aliased to `webshare` on my system, so it becomes simply `command | webshare`. The added xclip at the end gets the url into the X clipboard; it's not on every system, and there are several other tools out there like it.

Answer (score 4):

I use [ix.io](http://ix.io) with an account set up in .netrc with its command line tool installed; its simple and cool.

Then you can either pipe stuff through it like the above answer:

```
command which produces output | ix
```

or directly paste a file:

```
ix <filename>
```

this returns the url.

Then I additionally set up a git alias for this so that I can easily paste my format-patches and get an url for it:

```
~/.gitconfig:
[alias]    
  post = !sh -c 'git format-patch --stdout $1 | ix' -
```

To paste a patch I do, for example:

```
git post HEAD~1
```

or to paste whatever is in your current buffer in vim:

```
:w ! ix
```

for uploading files, not too big: http://paste.xinu.at/ with its client.

Comment: The real power behind `ix.io` for me is the ability to re-use fixed URLs, by editing my own posts via an account & token.

Comment: Interesting but how to install it? What is its client tool?